# How to say "in the last few months"

Tags: english-to-german, adjective

"In the last months" can be translated straightforwardly as

> In den letzten Monaten.

For "in the last few months", would it be

> In den letzten einigen Monaten

or

> In den einigen letzten Monaten

or neither of those is correct?

Comment: *einige* doesn't work here, you should use [*paar*](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1197/5016): In den letzten paar Monaten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither of those are correct; The *few* is already implied in "In den letzten Monaten" - you wouldn't say that if you actually meant many months. As fifaltra pointed out, you could add "paar" to make it more obvious.

Comment: Oder `in den wenigen, letzten Monaten`, aber auch ich meine, dass das `wenige` sich von selbst versteht. Spontan fällt mir auch kein Kontext ein, in dem man viele Monate meinen würde.

Comment: *in den letzten paar* wäre aus meiner Sicht die korrekte "vollständige" Übersetzung. Die Bedeutung *wenige* für *few* ist mir auch im Kopf, aber ich glaube, dann müsste die Word-Order im Originalsatz ein bisschen anders sein: *the few last months of his life* oder *the few last days we had together*.

Answer (score 1):

"In den letzten Monaten" is fine, your other examples would be wrong.

"In letzter Zeit" can be used if the context is clear or not that important (e.g. "In letzter Zeit sind die Preise für Benzin gestiegen")

I would not use "paar", in my opinion it is slang in this context. At least i would not write it down that way, though i actually might say it.

You can also say "Während der letzten Monate" 
The exact translation would be 'during the last few months' and this does not mean the same as "In den letzten Monaten" - the difference is the same as in english.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 'in den letzten paar Monaten' or 'während der letzten paar Monate.'

Comment: Glad to see the genitive case in use :)